# Docker non mounting volume

Tags: docker

Here is the situation on a clean docker-machine environment:

```
➜  momestock  docker-machine start momestock                                    
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
➜  momestock  eval "$(docker-machine env momestock)"
➜  momestock  echo 'Helo world!' > hello.txt
➜  momestock  ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrea andrea 4096 Oct 30 11:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 andrea andrea 4096 Oct 29 19:49 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 andrea andrea   12 Oct 30 11:39 hello.txt
➜  momestock  pwd
/home/andrea/projects/momestock
➜  momestock  docker run -v /home/andrea/projects/momestock:/tmp busybox ls -la /tmp
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Oct 30 10:39 .
drwxr-xr-x   18 root     root          4096 Oct 30 10:39 ..
➜  momestock
```

Is that a permissions problem? Or uids?

The problem appears with busybox but also every other container.

---

EDIT [SOLVED]:

looks like it's docker-machine's normal behavior to not bind mount

Comment: I tried, but can not reproduced in my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that docker-machine doesn't bind mount. It's the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What OS do you use? Try to add 777 permissions just for check.

Comment: I figured it out. It is simply docker-machine behavior, that doesn't bind mount.